Azure App Service Log Stream link is incorrect for some users: logStream-quickstart
Log Stream for Azure App Services works for some users, but not for others. I've noticed that the link for Log Stream shows up in two different places on the Azure App Service blade and has a different URL depending on where it shows up. Both users are both Contributors + Owners on the subscription (inherited by the App Service). This is not specific to a particular App Service.
Bad log stream
Under General / Log Stream.
[Picture of location on blade].

Link:
https://portal.azure.com/?feature.msaljs=true#@company.onmicrosoft.com/resource/subscriptions/%7Bsubscription%7D/resourceGroups/%7BresourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/%7BappServiceName%7D/logStream-quickstart
This does not display logs.
Working log stream
Under Monitoring / Log Stream. [Picture of location on blade].

Link:
https://portal.azure.com/?feature.msaljs=true#@company.onmicrosoft.com/resource/subscriptions/%7Bsubscription%7D/resourceGroups/%7BresourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/%7BappServiceName%7D/logStream
This displays logs as expected. This same behavior applies to all App Services.
Notice the difference is the very end of the link: logStream vs logStream-quickstart. Any ideas why this would be different and what I can do for the users that it doesn't work for?

Even I found the difference in UI for Payed and free subscription.
Free Trial Subscription:
Here you can see the App has Log stream option under Monitoring Section.

Paid Subscription:
Whereas for Paid Subscription you can see the option is in General section as you mentioned.


Initially both the logs display the same.



Enable the Application logging and change the log level in App Service logs section (for any UI).


I can see logs for both the Subscription UI's.
Output:


AFAIK, the issue is not with the Azure.

Thank you for the response, however this issue occurs for different users on the same App Services. The URL and location on the blade is different even though the App Service they are looking at is the same App Service.
